# understanding a psad error for src 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000

Tags: linux, icmp, psad

My server is generating this psad error. I am not sure what it means? I *think* it is saying an IPv6 ping request was blocked but am not sure.

And if it is a ping request, is it from the server to another device? I don't recall anything on my network being IPv6 enabled so I'm confused what it could/would be.

```
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= Sat Mar  9 22:50:28 2019 =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=


         Danger level: [2] (out of 5)


               Source: 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000
                  DNS: [No reverse dns info available]

          Destination: ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0016
                  DNS: [No reverse dns info available]

   Overall scan start: Sat Mar  9 22:50:28 2019
   Total email alerts: 1
      Syslog hostname: vm

         Global stats: 
                       chain:   interface:  protocol:  packets:  
                       OUTPUT   enp0s3      icmp6      1         


[+] ICMP6 scan signatures:

   Invalid ICMP type "143" chain=OUTPUT packets=1

[+] Whois Information (source IP):
No whois server is known for this kind of object.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= Sat Mar  9 22:50:28 2019 =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ICMPv6 type 143 is Version 2 Multicast Listener Report as defined in RFC 3810. It is sent from your node to the local router(s) to advertise its ability (or inability) to receive multicast traffic.

It's a bit bizarre that PSAD would call this traffic "Invalid" as MLDv2 has only been around for 15 years.

PSAD appears to be an active project; you should report this problem to its developers via whatever bug tracking system they use.